# ARP issuse in SUSE Linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing, arp, sles

I am dealing with a very strange problem. I have a VM running SLES 11 SP4 in VMware Environment. The machine has two NIC. All of a sudden the second NIC stopped working. It's not even pinging the gateway.

There does not seem to have changed in network configuration and it's exactly similar to another server in environment. So I am bit lost now and need help to fix this issue

The Second NIC is configured with 10.183.22.x series. It should ping the gateway 10.183.22.1

I tried removing second NIC from vmware and
- re-attached it several times 
- reconfigured IP address 
- Used another IP address range 
- brought down/up second network NIC multiple times
- Stopped SUSE firewall service
- Restarted network service

But nothing seems to work. OS can detect link on network adapter. Ifconfig shows RX/TX packets as well. So i don't think it's a vmware issue. It's more of OS related issue.

Here is the output from ethtool

```
ethtool eth3
Settings for eth3:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full 
                            10000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Speed: 10000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: uag
    Wake-on: d
    Link detected: yes
```

Here is the routing table

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.183.22.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
172.16.32.0     10.183.22.1     255.255.255.224 UG    0      0        0 eth3
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Ifconfig output

```
ifconfig eth3
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:84:39:32  
          inet addr:10.183.22.77  Bcast:10.183.22.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:110933 errors:0 dropped:113 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8488881 (8.0 Mb)  TX bytes:316982 (309.5 Kb)
```

ping output

```
ping 10.183.22.1
PING 10.183.22.1 (10.183.22.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.183.22.77: icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.183.22.77 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.183.22.77 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.183.22.77 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```